# Python vs Anaconda installation

Tags: python, anaconda

I am really new to Python and taking baby steps. I have installed Anaconda. I understand that Python installs by default as part of Anaconda. My problems are the following.

1. Most of the help contents that I get online used "command prompt" to code. But I have invested significant time in "Jupyter" environment which comes with ANaconda. Are there any risks associated with it ?
2. I simply dont get the requirement of defining a "path" for python while installing packages and some other use cases. Since I have installed Python through Anaconda, will this influence the "path" ?
3. Can anybody suggest some online material or pdf which covers some basics of Python. Whatever material I find online is too overwhelming for my level of knowledge. (I am an electrical engineer with very minimal exposure to coding apart from academics)

**To all readers and support community: I understand that my questions are too childish. But I am stuck up somewhere. Thank you for bearing with me. Hope I will be able to raise my level with some help**

Answer (score 0):

1. this website has great tutorials:
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/?ref=leftbar
   (GeeksforGeeks.org) have some of the most straightforward tutorials there are.
2. The path is simply describing the physical location in your machine you are storing python and all of its libraries. Since you are using anaconda, you have installed a lot more libraries that are used for topics like machine learning.

Starting with a tutorial will usually explain concepts like installation. Personally, I like geeksforgeeks. Freecodecamp is a great resource too.

It's super easy to get overwhelmed so keep grinding and it will make sense. We've all been there LOL.

Comment: and no there arent risks when using jupyter, its a editor that alot of data scientists use due to you being able to write and code and markdown in the same file!

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Keep helping.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no risks in using jupyter. It's a great environment to experiment.
   As you move on, you will probably want to make scripts that you can run independently.  In that case you'll need an editor.  I believe anaconda has spyder included, but I have never really used it. Visual Studio Code is quite popular, but needs te be installed on its own.  It will have no problem working with your anaconda python.
2. a path is normally something you only have to set once, during installation.
3. Other great tutorials to get started: https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Keep helping.